# Difficulty saving image path with name to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that saves images to a folder and the path folder to a SQL Server database. I am able to save the images to a folder but the column in the SQL Server table only saves the path as `C:\Images` without the image name of the image attached. Example: I want to store `C:\Images\cat.jpg` in the table column.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

I have declared this as global variables:

```
string displayimg, filePath,location;
string folderpath = @"C:\Images";
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
```

This codes opens the picture box:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    // image filters  
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // display image in picture box  
        displayimg = open.SafeFileName;
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

        txtpath.Text = open.FileName;
        filePath = open.FileName;
        location = open.FileName;
    }
}
```

Here is the saving code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO jimmy (Id, FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Address, City, Country, Image ) VALUES (@Id, @FirstName, @LastName, @Telephone, @Address, @City, @Country, @Image)", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", lblID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfirstname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlastname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", txttelephone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtaddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtcity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", txtcountry.Text);
    // saves images path and name to table
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", folderpath + Path.GetFileName(open.FileName));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Saved");

    //saves images to folder
    File.Copy(filePath, Path.Combine(folderpath, Path.GetFileName(filePath)), true);
    cleartext();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you have open declared globally and in scope of the button2_Click method. filePath is getting set to the value you want in the button2_Click method. So in the button2_Click remove the declaration for open and in the button1_Click method, change

> folderpath + Path.GetFileName(open.FileName)

to

> filePath

This is why globals should be used very sparingly. Ideally, you would call a method and those values would be returned, stored, and passed into a different method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm getting an error:String or binary data would be truncated. on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line

Comment: @Nelly that is a SQL error caused by a field having more data than the column can accept (i.e. a VARCHAR(10) field and you might be trying to put in 11 characters)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean thanks alot. had to change my column to varcharmax

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", folderpath + Path.GetFileName(open.FileName));
```

To...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("image", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Path.Combine(folderpath,Path.GetFileName(open.FileName)) });
```

Comment: hello,i tried your code but I am still getting the same results. The filename is not being added

Comment: @Nelly Can you confirm what Path.Combine is returning?

Comment: It returned "c:\Images" without the name of the name of the image

Comment: @Nelly is open.FileName populated? What is the data type of the SQL column?

Comment: @danielshillock l had a work around it, l changed the code to  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", Path.Combine(folderpath,Path.GetFileName(filePath)));. That solved it..Thanks for your help...much appreciated!